# Using Python to extract Twitter API data - Counting Tweets

Tags: python, api, search, twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter API to extract the number of tweets from specific users during a week-long period last fall.  The idea is to search the usernames of NFL players and count how many times each one tweeted during a week leading up to a game.

I know I can get the list of user_ids using `users/show`

I noticed that `statuses_count:` shows the value of the total number of tweets of all time from a user.  I tried adding `since 2013-12-01` and `until 2013-12-08` in `search/tweets` and a few other options with no luck.  Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Ideally I would use a csv to plug a user name into a search loop that python could iterate on to deliver the number of tweets for specific users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the `search/tweets` will not return an exhaustive list of tweets anyway because not all tweets are indexed, and only the popular ones will remain indexed for some time. See the [Twitter FAQ troubleshooting](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#troubleshooting) at *"Why are the Tweets I'm looking for not in Twitter Search, the Search API, or Search widgets?"*.

What you could do is query the entire list of tweets of the users you're inspecting. Then filter for the dates you are looking for. You can use the [`statuses/user_timeline` endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) for this.

However, you can "only" retrieve the last 3,200 tweets per user, so if the period is too far in the past or if the users are very active, you might not get relevant data. But for most use-cases, it should give you good results.

Comment: I tried testing this on the Twitter Dev Console, and when I put in the field `until` and the date `2013-12-01` it still gave me tweets as of yesterday

Comment: `until` is not a valid parameter for `statuses/timeline`. You have to loop through *all* tweets until you get to the tweets in your desired timeframe. Here's how you use [work with Twitter Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines) in the API.